# how to get code to print vertically

Tags: java

So I am having trouble printing my code vertically, no matter what I do, it continues to print horizontally. The first image is how my output looks like and the second image is what it should be.

```
// pixel counter

for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixelcounter [s.nextInt()/ binwidth] += 1;
    }
}

// histogram
for (int q = 0; q < pixelcounter.length; q++) {
    if (binmin < 10) {
        System.out.print(" " + binmin + ":");
        } else {
        System.out.print(binmin + ":");
    }
    int num_stars = (int) ((((double) pixelcounter[q] * 100.0/ area)) + 0.5)
    for (i = 0; i < num_stars; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    binmin += binwidth;
}
```

[image: this is what the output currently looks like]

[image: this is what the output is supposed to look like]

Comment: Should I assume this has nothing to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Also, you are using `.print`, you want `.println`

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
System.out.println(" " + binmin + ":");
```

If you use `System.out.print(" " + binmin + ":");` it would print everything in the same line.

Changing it to println will make sure that your output is printed on separate lines.

Comment: while that does work, it's not exactly how i'm trying to get to print vertically

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as printing vertically. What you might want to do is to create empty matrix/2D array and fill it (from left) with your data. For constant length or row, you insert astrix (*) where you have data and space " " where you don't. Then you transpose matrix and print line-by-line.